# After login depending on the user type dashboard will be displayed

Tags: codeigniter

After login depending on the client_type I want to  display a dashboard in codeigniter. Please help.

Here is my controller login:

```
public function login()
{
    $data['error'] ="Invalid Login";
    $this->load->view('auth/header');
    if($this->input->post())
       {
         $user = $this->UserModel->login($this->input->post());
        if(count($user)>0)
        {
            $array = array(
                        'client_id' => $user['client_id'],
                        'email' => $user['email'],
                        'password' => $user['password'],
                         );
            $this->session->set_userdata($array);

        }
        else
        {
         $data["error_message"]="Invalid User Name and Password combination";
        }

        //$this->UserModel->login($this->input->post());
        //redirect(base_url('../fms'));
       }
    $this->load->view('auth/signin',$data);
    $this->load->view('auth/footer');

}
```

Comment: Is there a `client_type` in the returned `$user`? If yes, why don't you use it to redirect the user to the proper dashboard? If no, then you should store and return that kind of information.

Comment: yes there is client_type_id

Comment: i have two client_types if client_type_id is 1 it has to go to admin dashboard and client_type_id is 2 it has to go to user dashboard

Comment: I would store the client type in the session. I would create a controller for each type of users and then I would redirect the user to the appropriate dashboard according to his type.

Comment: can you please explain in code how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this will may help you,

```
public function login()
{
$data['error'] ="Invalid Login";
$this->load->view('auth/header');
if($this->input->post())
   {
     $user = $this->UserModel->login($this->input->post());
    if(count($user)>0)
    {
        $array = array(
                    'client_id' => $user['client_id'],
                    'email' => $user['email'],
                    'password' => $user['password'],
                    'username' => $user['username']
                     );
        $this->session->set_userdata($array);
        if($user['client_type_id'] == '1'){
            redirect(base_url('your_controller/admin_dashboard'));
        } else {
            redirect(base_url('your_controller/client_dashboard'));
        }

    }
    else
    {
     $data["error_message"]="Invalid User Name and Password combination";
    }

    //$this->UserModel->login($this->input->post());
    //redirect(base_url('../fms'));
   }
$this->load->view('auth/signin',$data);
$this->load->view('auth/footer');

}

function admin_dashboard(){ 
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/home',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}

function client_dashboard(){
    $this->load->view('client/header');
    $this->load->view('client/home',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/footer');
}
```

Comment: how to display a name username on the dashboard after login

Comment: take username in your session and after that you can display username wherever you want in dashboard like this,

    echo $this->session->userdata('username');

Comment: i want to display that username in the top of  my header

Comment: <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/admin.jpg" alt="admin-pic">
    </a>

Comment: this is my header image in that image i want to replace a username